# Schedule a task with parameter

Tags: powershell, scheduler

i am scheduling a task using below code

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction "powershell.exe "C:\Scripts\Health.ps1""
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 12:30pm
```

now when there are 2 parameters which needs to be attached to it. so when i manually run i do like below

```
.\Health.ps1 -Log -ReportMode
```

-Log is for generating log and -ReportMode is to enable html report

Now when i did the same while scheduling the script, it is not generating the html report. Log writing is happening correctly.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Without showing the code of your `Health.ps1` file it is impossible to say why that doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the executable and the argument string to `New-ScheduledTaskAction` separately:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute powershell.exe -Argument "C:\Scripts\Health.ps1 -Log -ReportMode"
```